# Laravel 5.6 session not redirect to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and facing some problems. I want to authenticate a User if `email` and `password` found in Database match then redirect. If the User exists, redirect to `"user1"`,  otherwise redirect to `"/"`: also atttached the Migrations file

**Routes**

```
Route::any('/user1','UserProfile@store');
Route::get('/login','StudentController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $info = array(
        "Email" => $request->get("email"),
        "password" => $request->get("password")
    );

    $info = DB::table("students")->where($info)->first();

    if(!$info){
        $data = array(
            "user_email" => $info->Email,
            "user_password" => $info->password,
            "user_id" => $info->Student_id
        );

        $request->session()->put($data);
        $request->session()->get('user_email');

        //echo $val=$request->session()->get('user_id');die;
        //  print_r($data);die;

        return redirect('/user1');
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**Migrations**

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->string('Name');
        $table->string('Student_id');
        $table->string('Email');
        $table->string('Department');
        $table->string('Gender');
        $table->string('password');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

[This Is Picture of Database Table Students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu3JN.png)

Comment: Your question is full of typo, please [edit] it to correct please.

Comment: I'll make a note of this now, but storing plain-text passwords in a database is a very bad idea. Attempting to create your own authentication system when Laravel has one also seems backwards; use what's available to avoid security issues, or install a package like Sentinel (https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) for Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!$info)` is backwards logic; you're trying to create `$data` from `null` (`->first()` will return a `stdClass` object or `null`, depending on what it finds, and that code will only execute if `$info` is `null`).

It should be

```
if($info){
    $data = array(
        "user_email" => $info->Email,
        "user_password" => $info->password,
        "user_id" => $info->Student_id
    );

    $request->session()->put($data);
    $request->session()->get('user_email');

    return redirect('/user1');
} else {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying  I use this logic also If($info) but thy always redirect to '/' but my concern if I put emil and password that should goes to '/usee1' page

Comment: That just means that your query is returning `null`; are you entering correct email and password? Is password hashed? Should it be `email` and not `Email`? There's lots of causes for `null` results from a query.

Comment: i use dd($data)  so that thy show information that available in database

Comment: public function up() { Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->string('Name'); $table->string('Student_id'); $table->string('Email'); $table->string('Department'); $table->string('Gender'); $table->string('password'); $table->timestamps(); }); }

Comment: sorry im using first time that platform

Comment: It's fine. So the issue isn't `email` vs `Email`, and there's data in your database. Put a `dd("Got here");` above your `return redirect("/user1");`, submit your form with real data and see if you get there.

Comment: when I enter dd($data) above redirect user1 then its show the values of emil and password

Comment: but when I comment dd($data) then its again redirect to "/"

Comment: Then, unless there is additional redirect logic on your `/user1` route, you should be getting redirected to `/user1` without issue.

Comment: how? do this  im confused for this

Comment: I don't know, and I don't know how I'm going to debug this further... From everything you've posted in your question, you should not be getting redirected to `/` if you enter a valid email/password.

Comment: Sorry I can't do more; update your question with your updated code; possible someone else will see something I missed.

Comment: can you suggested advance topic base on laravel

Comment: Like a tutorial? 'Fraid not. I've been working with Laravel since 4.2, and learned on the job from a coworker, so my tutorial knowledge is pretty low.